# How do I change query in my google JSON Search API?

Tags: json, api, google-custom-search

I have used the example below successfully for my own cse search engine by changing cx and API-key. I am now creating a form for my users to be able to change the query. I therefore want to change the &q=cars in the example to a string that changes according to form input. My string name is que and I have tried &q=" + que + " and about a thousand other ways without success. I either get a search result list for the word que or no results at all? Any ideas? How is the proper syntax supposed to be?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JSON Custom Search API Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
      function hndlr(response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
        var item = response.items[i];
        // in production code, item.htmlTitle should have the HTML entities escaped.
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<br>" + item.htmlTitle;
      }
    }
    </script>
    <script src="https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=YOUR-KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=cars&callback=hndlr">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a good idea to use the JSON API in client-side code running in a browser, since your API key will be viewable by anybody.

You should use the Custom Search Element for this case: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/implementingsearchbox

Comment: You could use this guy's custom Google Search Engine script: https://github.com/kisenka/google-custom-search - it works out of the box...